# Do not match Expected Integer type

Tags: haskell

I am a beginner in **Haskell** and doing **Count of positives / sum of negatives** from codewars. Here below is my code

```
module Kata where

countPositivesSumNegatives :: Maybe [Int] -> [Int]
countPositivesSumNegatives xs = if null xs 
                                    then [] 
                                    else [length [x | x <- xs, x > 0], sum[x | x <- xs, x < 0]]
```

When I compiled the code it gives this error

```
src/Kata.hs:6:60: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘[Integer]’
                  with actual type ‘Maybe [Int]’
    • In the expression: xs
      In a stmt of a list comprehension: x <- xs
      In the first argument of ‘length’, namely ‘[x | x <- xs, x > 0]’
  |
6 |                                     else [length [x | x <- xs, x > 0], sum[x | x <- xs, x < 0]]
  |                                                            ^^

src/Kata.hs:6:85: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘[Int]’
                  with actual type ‘Maybe [Int]’
    • In the expression: xs
      In a stmt of a list comprehension: x <- xs
      In the first argument of ‘sum’, namely ‘[x | x <- xs, x < 0]’
  |
6 |                                     else [length [x | x <- xs, x > 0], sum[x | x <- xs, x < 0]]
  |                                                                                     ^^
```

I don't know what `countPositivesSumNegatives :: Maybe [Int] -> [Int]` is doing here. I think it is a function definition. Could anyone please explain me what is this?

Comment: why `countPositivesSumNegatives` accepts a `Maybe [Int]`  as input parameter instead of just `[Int]`

Comment: ok , `countPositivesSumNegatives` is a function definition but it is wrong because assumes the input parameter as a list of ints, but it is annotated as an optional list of ints.

Comment: Because if we pass  empty array or null then it should return an empty array

Comment: What's a "null"?

Comment: I'd suggest you pattern match on `xs` so you can realize what's happening

Comment: check this https://www.codewars.com/kata/576bb71bbbcf0951d5000044/train/haskell

Comment: @FyodorSoikin `null` is [a function](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:null). Since `xs :: Maybe [Int]`, in this case, it returns `True` iff `xs` is `Nothing` and `False` otherwise. What I suspect OP _expects_ it to do, on the other hand, is return `True` if the list is empty, which is what it _would_ do if `xs` were a list instead of just "maybe a list."

Comment: The empty list `[]` still has type `[Int]`, not `Maybe [int]`. Unless you need to distinguish between `Nothing` and `Just []`, you almost certainly don't need a `Maybe` argument.

Comment: `0` is both a valid count and a valid sum, so are you sure you don't want to return `[0, 0]` if the input is empty? (That also means you don't need to distinguish between empty and non-empty arguments at all.)

Comment: (`[Int]` is also too broad a type if you will always return two `Int` values; `(Int, Int)` would be more appropriate.)

Comment: Perhaps you intended `[Int] -> Maybe [Int]`? Or `[Int] -> Maybe (Int, Int)`? Or even `[Int] -> (Int, Maybe Int)`?

Comment: To all the people suggesting changing the type signature: The asker is solving a challenge exercise where this type is given. This type cannot be changed. See the codewars link in a comment above.

Comment: @Noughtmare fair enough, though I have to say this challenge looks pretty silly. It's certainly not too helpful for learning. Giving the result as a list that has either zero or two entries is very poor interface design.

Comment: Thanks everyone for helping me. Just need to use `case` instead of `if-else`.

Comment: @Abhijit Please be aware that this particular kata is *not* indicative of how you would actually write Haskell code. It's just a naïve translation of a problem original written in a language with a much poorer type system. In Haskell, you would define a function of type `[Int] -> (Int, Int)`, and let the caller worry about making sure they have an actual list of integers (empty or not) to use as an argument, and being clear about returning *exactly* a length and a count.

Comment: @AndrewRay I meant in the context of "_Because if we pass empty array or null..._"

Comment: That Kata looks horrible. As others have said, keep in mind that the way the kata is written in codewars is extremely unidiomatic Haskell, that's why many of us were so confused with this question. Follow Chepner's advice.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to write if null xs then ... else ..., because type of mxs :: Maybe [Int] and type of null :: [a] -> Bool, to solve this problem, you need to unpack the list from Maybe:

```
countPositivesSumNegatives :: Maybe [Int] -> [Int]
countPositivesSumNegatives mxs = case mxs of
    Nothing -> []
    Just a -> if null a then [] else (\xs -> [length [x | x <- xs, x > 0], sum [x | x <- xs, x < 0]]) mxs
```

And we can rewrite this code with maybe function in Data.Maybe:

```
-- maybe :: b -> (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> b

countPositivesSumNegatives :: Maybe [Int] -> [Int]
countPositivesSumNegatives mxs = case mxs of
    Just [] -> []
    otherwise -> maybe [] (\xs -> [length [x | x <- xs, x > 0], sum [x | x <- xs, x < 0]]) mxs
```

P.s. idk why, but in codewars Just [0] should return [], new code:

```
countPositivesSumNegatives :: Maybe [Int] -> [Int]
countPositivesSumNegatives mxs = case mxs of
    Just [] -> []
    Just [0] -> []
    otherwise -> maybe [] (\xs -> [length [x | x <- xs, x > 0], sum [x | x <- xs, x < 0]]) mxs
```